# Multiline comments in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

Does MIPS (as implemented in the SPIM assembler specifically) support the multiline commenting of code? Because it'd be very tedious to use single-line comments every time you needed to comment out a block of code.

Comment: Use an editor that supports a "comment block" command?

Comment: Well, the Sublime Text editor I'm using can't toggle block comments for MIPS code.

Comment: No, `spim` [nor `mars`, etc.] does not support multiline comments. I think you just need to become more proficient with your editor. When I need to do this, in `vi`, I scroll to the top line and do `ma` [setting mark 'a']. I scroll to the bottom line and do `mb`. Then, I do `:'a,'bs/^/###/<cr>`. The `###` is my convention for commented out lines. To reverse, do `:'a,'bs/^###//<cr>`. You can also add a "jump around". `j skip_commented_out_block` `instructions to comment out ...` and then `skip_commented_out_block:`

Answer (score 3):

Old thread but here's my quick cheat in sublime. MIPS uses the same comment syntax as python so I just switch to python syntax and multi line comment.